# Объединение машин в одну сеть

Tags: сеть, openvpn

Доброго дня! Имеется несколько машин в стороннем предприятии, эти машины расположены в разных подсетях. На одной из них есть выход в интернет и установлен впн-клиент. Чтобы попасть на остальные приходится заходить на машину с впн и через нее на остальные. Подскажите, возможно ли как-то объединить только свои машины в одну сеть с впн и заходить на них напрямую?

Answer (score 2):

Есть два варианта:

- Установить VPN-клиенты на остальные машины и подключаете их к сети.
- Добавить в маршруты, раздаваемые сервером VPN, добавить маршрут, ведущий в подсети машин на предприятии, на которых нет VPN-клиента, а на машине с выходом в интернет включить маршрутизацию трафика в эти сети.